# Attempting to insert a FK into a table without the User manually inputting the FK on the page ASP.NET / C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

As said in the title, I am attempting to insert a FK into a table without the User manually inputting the FK on the page. I have a ListView populated by a SELECT statement that draws from a table in my database. How this begins, is the user selects an examination from the previous page (saves the PK for the Examination table in a Session variable) and proceeds to the Maintain_Questions.aspx page which will show them the questions created specifically for that examination. The FK I am attempting to insert into the table is the ExaminationID (I am assuming this is done through a SessionParameter). Currently I feel I am extremely close to the solution, perhaps just missing one line in the SqlDataSource that is keeping me from inserting the question properly. Side note: the ListView does insert the question into the question table, however it is not inserting the appropriate FK along with it - so the ExaminationID is seen as NULL in the database table. 
Thank you for any assistance!

Code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sdsListViewQuestion"
    ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:OPT%>" 
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
    SelectCommand="SELECT QuestionID, Question, CorrectAnswer, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC, OptionD, Examination.ExaminationID, Examination.Examination
                     FROM Question, Examination
                     WHERE Examination.ExaminationID = @ExaminationID
                     AND Examination.ExaminationID = Question.ExaminationID
                     ORDER BY Examination
                     ;"
     InsertCommand="INSERT
                      INTO Question
                         ( 
                           Question,
                           CorrectAnswer,
                           ExaminationID,
                           OptionA,
                           OptionB,
                           OptionC,
                           OptionD
                         )
                    VALUES
                         (
                           @Question,
                           @CorrectAnswer,
                           @ExaminationID,
                           @OptionA,
                           @OptionB,
                           @OptionC,
                           @OptionD                            
                         ) ;
                    SELECT ExaminationID = @ExaminationID;"
     UpdateCommand="UPDATE Question
                       SET Question = @Question,
                           CorrectAnswer = @CorrectAnswer,
                           ExaminationID = @ExaminationID,
                           OptionA = @OptionA,
                           OptionB = @OptionB,
                           OptionC = @OptionC,
                           OptionD = @OptionD
                     WHERE QuestionID = @original_QuestionID;" 
     DeleteCommand="DELETE
                      FROM Question
                     WHERE QuestionID = @original_QuestionID;">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Direction="Input" Name="ExaminationID" SessionField="intExaminationID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Direction="Output" Name="ExaminationID" SessionField="intExaminationID" Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Direction="Output" Name="ExaminationID" SessionField="intExaminationID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Every FK is just another tables PK. Let the user select the PK, use it. Have a UI Element (Dialog or other) where the user can select the PK in a proper Select/Update/Delete Form. Ideally make it a Dialog for Programm Flow reasons.

Comment: The PK for the examination selection page is selected and saved in a session variable for use on the next page, being the Maintain_Question page. Attempting to save/insert the (now) FK of the selected examination once the question is created and inserted into the Question table.

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue, the direction for the SessionParameter I was establishing was set to "Output" and not "Input" for the InputParameters. Adjusting this was allowing me to be able to input the correct session variable for the FK (ExaminationID) into the Question table accordingly.